# Filtering array, and adding search functionality

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So where to begin, I have nested json array and 3 Components they are pulling the data from JSON, each Component is taking a different array in a JSON file. So the thing I am trying to do is this. I want to make a Search functionality, that 'functionality' would go through the arrays and based on a specific Id it would display the name of that specific object in the array. I have already tried something but, I don't exactly know, if I am going the right path I am trying to filter them. If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

```
import React from 'react'
App Component
function App({searchValue}) {

  const filteredGames = games.filter((games) => {
    return games.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  });
  return (
    <div className="app">
          <Header/>
         <Route path="/action">
          <Action games={filteredGames} />
          </Route>
           <Route path="/adventure">
            <Adventure games={filteredGames}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <FreeToPlay games={filteredGames}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>  
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


json

[
  {
    "freetoplay": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "CS Go"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "6$",
        "name": "Fifa"
      }
    ],
    {
      "action": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "60$",
          "name": "doom"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "66$",
          "name": "cyberpunk"
        }
      ],
      "adventure": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "60$",
          "name": "indiana "
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "43$",
          "name": "torchlight"
        }
      ],
    }
  ]

import React from 'react'
import data from "../data.json";
import {
    
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";

function FreeToPlay() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>
            {data[0].freetoplay.map((postData) => {
              return (
                <div key={postData.id}>
                    <h1>{postData.image}</h1>
                    <h1>{postData.name}</h1>              
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}

export default FreeToPlay


import React from 'react';
import data from "../data.json";


function Adventure() {
    return (
        <div className="Awhater">
          <div>
            {data[0].adventure.map((postData) => {
              return (
                <div key={postData.id}>
                  <h1>{postData.name}</h1>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
        }
export default Adventure

import React from 'react';
import data from "../data.json";


function Adventure() {
    return (
        <div className="Ahater">
          <div>
            {data[0].action.map((postData) => {
              return (
                <div key={postData.id}>
                  <h1>{postData.name}</h1>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
        }
export default Action

import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import Search from'./Search' 


function Header() {
const [searchValue, setSearchValue]= React.useState('')
 
  
    return (
        <div className='header'>
         <div className=''>
           <Search  searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} />
         </div>   
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header

import React from 'react'

function Search({ searchValue, setSearchValue }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <form class="search__Form">
            <input class="search__Input" type="text" value ={searchValue} 
            onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
            type='text'
            placeholder='Search Champion'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Search
```

Comment: Are you any issues with your current code?

Comment: games is not defined in App

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON array. Once you import the data from the JSON file, it's just a normal every day array. You may want to work on formatting your JSON; I don't think it has quite the structure you think it does...

Comment: What is rendering `App` to pass ` searchValue` prop to it? Seems your `searchValue` state resides in your `Header` and you need to lift state up to `App`.

Comment: @Drew Reese so Context Api

Comment: Sure. Or just move the state to `App` and pass `searchValue` and `setSearchValue` to the header component and use `searchValue` directly in the filter callback. A react context may be a little overkill for a single value and setter.

Comment: @Drew Reese I have done it it still gives me the games not defined in App Component.

Comment: What and where is `games` declared?

Comment: @DrewReese In app

Comment: There is no `games` declaration in `App` according to your snippet. If it's really there then please update your code snippets to be more complete.